# How to connect phantom wallet to certain site?

Tags: solana-program, transactions, solana-wallet-adapter, solana-cli, wallet

Hello how can i connect phantom wallet to certain sites with sol.py? I can't find any help materials to solve my problem when it comes to do it in pyth

Comment: You may need to clarify your question. On the web, Phantom runs as an extension, written in JS. Unless you have some sort of Python execution environment on the web, you won't be able to access the Phantom web wallet.